# Constants and literals explicit conversion

Tags: c#, unchecked-conversion

When i try the following :

```
const int x = 1000;
byte b1 = (byte)x;

//Or

byte b2 = (byte)1000;
```

The compiler claims that it didn't convert constant 1000 to b1 or b2.

But when i tried the following :

```
const int x = 1000;
byte b1 = unchecked((byte)x);

//Or

byte b2 = unchecked((byte)1000);
```

This code worked fine.Why?

Comment: Do you know what `unchecked` means in c#? You have to to understand why it works.

Comment: Because the maximum of a byte is 255.

Comment: I can't believe you couldn't make the effort to look that up on MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

> The compiler claims that it didn't convert constant 1000 to b1 or b2.

Yes because In .NET Framework, [`byte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte.aspx) represents 8-bit unsigned integer and it can hold the values from `0` to `255`.

> But when i tried the following... This code worked fine.Why?

When you use [`unchecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a569z7k8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keyword, you are allowing the overflow is not flagged.

> If the unchecked environment is removed, a compilation error occurs.
>   The overflow can be detected at compile time because all the terms of
>   the expression are constants.

Answer (score 3):

It is obvious.

`byte` has range 0-255. You are trying to put there 1000 which leads to overflow. `unchecked` allows it because

> The unchecked keyword is used to suppress overflow-checking for integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.